Numerically solving some systems of transcendental equations!
I want to calculate the area enclosed by the two functions in the following three examples:
(1)$${3^x=y^5+7y^4+51y^3+279y^2+1855y,2^y=x^4+19x^3+71x^2+619x}$$
(2)$${3^x=y^5+6y^4+62y^3+388y^2+1927y,2^y=x^4+18x^3+82x^2+888x}$$
(3)$${3^x=y^5+5y^4+98y^3+879y^2+2106y,2^y=x^4+17x^3+97x^2+972x}$$
Next here are links for the graphics of every one of the three equation systems:
(1)First System Of Equations
(2)Second System Of Equations
(3)Third System Of Equations
There are other solutions to the left of the graphic, but we don't care about them now. Using Wolfran Alpha's FindRoot I have obtained these two pairs of solutions:
(1){x->0.00161581, y->0.000539998} and {x->13.2522, y->16.5467}
(2){x->0.00112641, y->0.00051953} and {x->13.267, y->16.5985}
(3){x->0.00102904, y->0.000475277} and {x->13.3707, y->16.6514}
Q1: What algorithms can be employed in order obtain these results? That, as actually I am more interested in the process of finding these roots at this step rather then the results. I'm remembering vaguely from school something about systems of second degree equations that can be solved numerically (something with ellipses), but those do not apply here as these are transcendental equations.
Q2: To obtain the area I want I need to use two Integrals. I am not sure about which ones should I use. So the question is : Which integrals should I use and what operation should I make between them? Let's think about any of the examples. Let's call the two solutions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. The way I though about it is to first write both integrals as a function of x then integrate between $x_1$ and $x_2$ using the previously calculated $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively. Then delete from the orange integral the blue one (according to the Wolfram Alpha links I have posted above). This should work as a  function of y, too. Actually this could be a nice verification although a small numerical error should appear. But I am not sure about the details of this.

To be honest it's my birthday and in the morning I wanted to have some fun with transcendental equations. After seeing the solutions, I wondered what is the aria over there? And here we are. So if it is difficult for you, don't worry. For me it's all fun. Anyway, on a serious note, now you got me curious. Is there a theorem that approximates said area?  I am assuming that if the answer it's "Yes",  then during the proof there are some solutions approximations and integral calculations.

And by the way chatGPT - 4o has not mentioned anything about calculating the area directly.

Given the plane region:
$$
\color{green}{D=\left\{(x,y)\in[-1,14]\times[-1,17]:
\begin{aligned}
&3^x\le y^5+7y^4+51y^3+279y^2+1855y,\\
&2^y\le x^4+19x^3+71x^2+619x\\
\end{aligned}\right\}}
$$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
the simplest way to numerically approximate its area is by applying the Monte Carlo method.
The basic idea is to bombard with $10^n$ balls the rectangle of area $A_r$ which encloses the region of plane $D$ of interest which goes from vertex $(-1,-1)$ to vertex $(14,17)$ and to count the $m$ balls that also fall internally to $D$. The area of $D$ is therefore estimated by $A_r\,m/10^n$:
Table[m = 0; 
      Do[x = RandomReal[{-1, 14}];
         y = RandomReal[{-1, 17}];
         If[3^x <= y^5 + 7 y^4 + 51 y^3 + 279 y^2 + 1855 y &&
            2^y <= x^4 + 19 x^3 + 71 x^2 + 619 x, m = m + 1], {10^n}];
      270. m / 10^n, {n, 7}]


{81., 116.1, 134.19, 131.382, 130.154, 130.333, 130.226}

No intersections, no integrals, but rather you need a good pseudo-random real number generator.
On the other hand, knowing the boundary parameterization of $D$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&{\color{red}{\gamma_1:
\begin{cases}
x_1(t)=\frac{\ln(t^5+7t^4+51t^3+279t^2+1855t)}{\ln(3)}\\
y_1(t)=t\\
\end{cases},
\quad t\in[t_{1\min},t_{1\max}]\,;}}\\
&\\
&{\color{blue}{\gamma_2:
\begin{cases}
x_2(t)=t\\
y_2(t)=\frac{\ln(t^4+19t^3+71t^2+619t)}{\ln(2)}\\
\end{cases},
\quad t\in[t_{2\min},t_{2\max}]\,;}}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
it's possible to numerically approximate the area of ​​$D$ by applying the Gauss-Green theorem:
$$
\text{area}(D)=\int_{t_{1\min}}^{t_{1\max}}x_1(t)\,y_1'(t)\,\text{d}t+\int_{t_{2\max}}^{t_{2\min}}x_2(t)\,y_2'(t)\,\text{d}t\approx 130.225\,.
$$
In this other case, no pseudo-random real number generator is needed, but integrals appear whose integration extremes require the intersections! In particular, it's necessary to solve the equation:
$$
\underbrace{3^x-y^5-7y^4-51y^3-279y^2-1855y}_{f(x)}=0,\quad\text{with}\;y=\frac{\ln|x^4+19x^3+71x^2+619x|}{\ln(2)}
$$
which can be easily solved by applying the Newton-Raphson method:
$$
\text{while}\;|x_i-x_{i-1}|>10^{-10}\;:\;x_i=x_{i-1}-\frac{f(x_{i-1})}{f'(x_{i-1})}
$$
where, thanks to graphical inspection, in one case $x_0=1$ and in the other case $x_0=14$. So, by iterating, in the first case: $(x,y)\approx(0.00161581,0.000539998)$, while in the second case: $(x,y)\approx(13.2522, 16.5467)$.

While trying to think about more general cases, where the right side polynomials are not constant or linear in x and respectively in y, I got the notion that the monte carlo method is the more general.

I am not sure that in more complicated cases one can find a simple parametrization!

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your time!

I meant one cannot get an exact parametrization easily. I'll post soon a new question, if I don't manage it on my own.

There is the follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5009374/more-systems-of-transcendental-equations-to-be-characterized

This is too long for comments.
As @πρόσεχε showed in his/her answer, the problem reduce to finding the zero of function
$$f(x)=3^x-(1855 y+279 y^2+51 y^3+7 y^4+y^5)$$ where
$$y=\frac{\log \left(619 x+71 x^2+19 x^3+x^4\right)}{\log (2)}$$
If you plot $f(x)$, you will notice that it is not very nice while $g(x)=x\, f(x)$ looks much better (almost a parabola very close to $x=0$. So, if you apply Newton method, it would be better to apply it to $g(x)$.
In any manner, the problem is to have a reasonable guess for $x_0$. Admitting that we know that $x$ and $y$ are small, make a first approximation neglecting the high powers. This gives, by Taylor,
$$y=\frac{\log (x)+\log (619)}{\log (2)}+\frac{71 x}{619 \log   (2)}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ and then
$$f(x)\sim \Big(1+x \log (3)+O\left(x^2\right) \Big)-1855\Bigg( \frac{\log (x)+\log (619)}{\log (2)}+\frac{71 x}{619 \log   (2)}+O\left(x^2\right)\Bigg)$$ which shows an explicit solution in terms of Lambert function.
Converted to decimals, the result is $x_0=0.00161581$ which is the exact solution for this number of significant figures. It is so good that we can ignore $g(x)$; working with a ridiculous number of decimals, the successive iterates of Newton method will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_{(n)} \\
 0 & 0.00161581423214867910527581265609 \\
 1 & 0.00161581408227345209808061616797 \\
 2 & 0.00161581408227345603018801926078 \\
 3 & 0.00161581408227345603018801926078 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Edit
For the largest root, it would be good to consider
$$h(x)=x\log(3)-\log(y^5+7 y^4+51 y^3+279 y^2+1855y)$$ which is almost the problem of the intersection of two straight lines.
Starting with even a small $x_0$, the convergence would be quite fast as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_{(n)} \\
 0 & 5.000000000 \\
 1 & 13.82715442 \\
 2 & 13.25314698 \\
 3 & 13.25218266 \\
 4 & 13.25218266 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
